# Make code blocks containing URLs automatically <!-- language: lang-none -->

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, markdown

As I frequent the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, I see this quite often:

```java
http://www.example.net/app/showthread.php?tid=38798742343
```

As you can see, everything behind the `//` gets displayed in a grey color because Stack Overflow assumes this is java (and java starts line comments with `//`), since the question had been tagged as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

My proposal is that code blocks which start with a protocol (like `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, etc...) on over 70% of lines (to be discussed) automatically get converted to `<!-- language: lang-none -->` blocks.

```
http://www.example.net/app/showthread.php?tid=38798742343
```

Much nicer to look at, isn't it?

Of course, this does not only apply to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), but a lot of languages use similar comment syntax and suffer from the same problem.

Comment: the url shouldn't even be in a code block in the first place!

Comment: Same problem with anchors and languages that use `#` for comments: `http://www.example.com/foo#bar`. But I agree with Daniel, URLs generally don't belong in code blocks.

Comment: @DanielA.White What should be used instead? Inline backticks?

Comment: @RAnders00 a link or regular text.

Comment: @DanielA.White And if it's about some sort of theory around the URL, e.g. when discussing something like web server path mappings, where the URL does not actually point to anything?

Comment: @RAnders00 then just regular text

Comment: for anyone wondering about the large number of downvotes, downvotes on meta mean that users dislike the feature-request, NOT the question itself. i think the question was well-written.

Comment: @DanielA.White I wanted to show this earlier as well, but take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/4464702). How would you format it?

Answer (score 5):

In your example, `http` is a valid yet unused label in Java.  That is to say, if you put that into code right now, it'd compile, but any IDE worth their salt would alert you that you have a label that is now unused (and very, very likely broken even if it *were* used).

So no, that's no bug.

If it's outside of code, it shouldn't be in a code block at all (and removing it would be an improvement).  If it's inside of code, make sure it's prefix it with the appropriate line comment provided the OP really *didn't* intend to create a new label.

```
// http://www.example.net/app/showthread.php?tid=38798742343
```

Comment: It's more meant like people using it to just monospace URLs whilst outside of Java code.